# Import multiple CSV files, certain columns to a table in Access?

Tags: database, csv, ms-access

I'm trying to figure out a way to import certain columns from multiple csv files onto a table, so that I could create a graph on a form with the information that was imported.  The main issue I'm having with this is that I can't seem to isolate certain columns to import, as well as not knowing how the frames of the tables would be named, as all of the csv files have the same names for columns.

For example, the CSV files would all have columns 1, 2, 3, and 4, but for the purpose of the graph, I would only need columns 2 and 4. Ideally it would be some sort of appending system, as the number of CSV files might vary.

Comment: Import into a temporary table and then just query the columns you need.  `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet` function and Append/Update queries are good place to start if you're not too familiar.

Comment: That also has the issue of requiring to import multiple csv files to one table, where .  To my knowledge the Append/Update queries are not what I want, because what I want to append are frames, and not new records.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a frame, could you break it down for me?  As long as there is a way to identify which row belongs to which row across the tables, you can use append/update queries.

Comment: By Frame I mean the column in a table.  Currently the csv files all have 5 columns, and I would like to add those csv files to one single table.

Comment: Please edit your question with the details e.g columns available.  If you're combining the columns, on what field do you know they are related? ie how do you know row 1 of table A is lining up with row 10 of table B?

Comment: Hmm I see that that may also be an issue. I will have to rethink how I will solve this problem from scratch. Thanks for the comments.